# Multiple line search and replace bash sed

Tags: bash, sed, multiline, substitution

I have a file called tst.txt that contains text:

```
exec(compile(open(bla bla bla'))
DATE = "05JUN20"
Only capture the below line
params = {'System_Date': getparamDate(DATE), 'Param': '2'}
This Line should be available
''End

'Short description:
'bla bla bli, bla bla bla

First line with }
Normal Line without bracket
Another bracket}&
Then normal text
blabla 
blublu 
tatati
```

I want to capture and change only the line:

```
params = {'System_Date': getparamDate(DATE), 'Param': '2'}
```

in my file.

I've fond a sed command that allow to substitute what is between patterns. /c

```
sed -i '/params = {/,/}/c params = MyNewParam' tst.txt
```

where I intend to substitute only what is between:

```
params = {
```

and

```
} from the same line.
```

unfortunately, my regex will replace until First line with }

```
exec(compile(open(bla bla bla'))
DATE = "05JUN20"
Only capture the below line
params = MyNewParam
Normal Line without bracket
Another bracket}&
Then normal text
blabla 
blublu 
tatati 
I5TaxActivationDate
```

which is not what I expect.

I've seen that with

```
,/}/q
```

it's possible to stop at the first occurrence, I cannot find the right syntax.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If `}` is in the same line, why not simply `sed 's/params = {[^}]}/params = MyNewParam/ file'`?

Comment: it can be on several lines too...

Comment: If you are using GNU `sed` you can use `-z` option to match multiline.

Comment: This regex works very well with multilines, but not with single line. If I use ''End rather than } it works well. But I don't want to use this regex

Comment: `sed '/^params =/s/{[^}]*}/MyNewParam/' file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/params = {.*}/c CHANGE ONE' -e '/params = {/,/}/c CHANGE MULTIPLE' file
```

If a line contains the whole pattern then only change that line, otherwise try to fit the pattern over multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

Capture and return with back-reference `\1` `params` up to and including `{'` within the parenthesis.
Exclude everything up to `}` and replace with `MyNewParam`

```
$ sed -Ez "s/(params[^{]*\{')[^}]*/\1MyNewParam'/" input_file
exec(compile(open(bla bla bla'))
DATE = "05JUN20"
Only capture the below line
params = {'MyNewParam'}
This Line should be available
''End

'Short description:
'bla bla bli, bla bla bla

First line with }
Normal Line without bracket
Another bracket}&
Then normal text
blabla
blublu
tatati
```

Comment: It looks like it's working,
thanks a lot.
Can you please explain:
[^{]*\{')[^}]  ?

Comment: Thanks, so if I want to totally substitute the string, including params { , for instance, s@TOTO{bababab}@TATA{blublublu}@ with bababa that could include multilines?

Comment: @Totoc1001 Please be more concise. Where does `TOTO` come from? It is not in your question.

Comment: @Totoc1001, `-z` makes GNU `sed` multiline (but your pattern must match newlines too).